# qt-creator android deploy error

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-quick

```
QT: 5.9.3
qt-creator: 4.4.1
android API: 24
android SDK tools: 26.1.1
android NDK: 16.1
android phone: MI max, android-7.0, enable usb debug
```

1. Create a android quick control 2 application.(Everything is default)
2. Build successfully. (Got android-build-debug.apk file)
3. Run error. Application Output: `"org.qtproject.example.android1" died.` And I checked the phone, apk was not installed.
4. Use command line: `adb install -r android-build-debug.apk` **Apk can be installed and executed successfully**.
5. Both release and debug can't be executed from qt-creator.

I view some youtube and web tutorial. They just click `Run`, and program can be launched, no other configuration.

What's the wrong with my project or settings?

Run Settings:
[image: run settings]

Build Settings:
[image: build settings]

Android tool versions:
[image: android tool versions]

Device Settings:
[image: device settings]

Build Output:
[image: build output]

Run Output:
[image: run output]

Comment: everything looks alright, whats your device android version, also check the manifist file generated in build folder

Comment: My phone is android7.0 api-24. Project build with api-24. apk can be installed with adb command line.

Comment: try to uncheck _verbose mode_ in your settings ..

Comment: I added verbose mode after some failure tests. It does not affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the problem.

`Build & Run` -> `General` -> `Always deploy project before running it` should be checked.